# Console error in Angular Module federation remote app routing

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-routing, webpack-module-federation

I have a two angular (Home & Remote) application created with angular module federation.

From my home app If I try to access the remote app component directly, I am not getting the below console error. But I have new landing page in my remote app from the landing page if I try to navigate to the same remote components, I am getting this error.

[image]

**My Home application Routing file.**

[image]

**My Remote application webpack file**

[image]

**Remote app router file**

[image]

Thanks,

Comment: Better post a complete stackblitz of your code, there is a lot of code you are showing.
I'm quite sure for readability.
Are you able to access ```http://localhost:4230/remoteEntry.js``` ?
I'm not seeing where you expose the filename remoteEntry.js in your remote webpack file. ```filename: "remoteEntry.js"```,

Comment: @FolabiAhn, Remote application is working fine i am able to access them from shell application, problem is while doing the routing navigation internally in remote app.

Comment: Create a stackblitz for your issue so we can figure out better your issue